# python parse nginx log

Tags: python, mysql, nginx

I builded a video website, The structure of the site is very simple, An index page, a list page and a watching page. Now I want to count the clicked times of every watching page, the url structure of the watching page is: `/v/id.html`

Here is part of the log file:

```
58.52.168.119 - - [25/Aug/2014:00:00:30 +0800] "GET /v/31635.html HTTP/1.1" 200 10451 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0"
58.52.168.119 - - [25/Aug/2014:00:00:39 +0800] "GET /v/31635.html HTTP/1.1" 200 10451  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0"
125.85.189.50 - - [25/Aug/2014:00:00:42 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 44240  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1"
42.49.223.150 - - [25/Aug/2014:00:00:50 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 44240  "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)"
66.249.69.247 - - [25/Aug/2014:00:00:59 +0800] "GET /v/926.html HTTP/1.1" 200 10484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

I can get the click time, page id, from the log, but I don't know how to import these infomation into database. I want to define some method to access the statistic info.

```
get_yesterday_click(id)  #get yesterday's click times
get_last7days_click(id)  #get last week's click times
get_last30days_click(id) #get last month's click times
get_total_click(id)      #get the total click times
```

Anyone can help me on how to create the table and implement these methods?

Comment: It seemed like a `Code it for me` issue.

Comment: no, not code it for me. Just give me a hint. I tried several ways to store these data, but not not so good. And I want to see how do you guys store statistic infomation.

Comment: Do you know Google Analytics? If you can use it, you get lots of analysis for free.

Comment: I want to store these data into database. So have to write my own statistic program.

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem solved in a very ugly way.

first use python to parse the log file get an dictionary.

then write the dictionary to a file with json format.

use php to read the json file and write to database.
My `stat` table is like:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| cdate       | char(8)      | YES  |     |         |       |
| day_click   | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| week_click  | varchar(200) | YES  |     |         |       |
| month_click | varchar(500) | YES  |     |         |       |
| total_click | int(11)      | YES  |     | 1000    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

one test record is like:

```
| 31967 | 20140826 |         2 | 2,2,2,2,2,2 | 2,2,2,2,2,2 |          12 |
```

`week_click` and `month_click` are implemented as a queue.

Hope to see a better way to implement the statistic program.